# Extjs 4 application on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, extjs

I write very simple application, let's say bookshelf with info about author, tiltle and photo of this book (in BLOB). My database is MySQL 5.x.
On Windows (7) it's working propery without problems but when I copy this code to Suse I found lot of problems and application can't work (400, 404 and 500 HTML errors). 
Could anybody write, step by step, what should I do to run it on linux?

Comment: I think that such question does not belong here. You should edit your question and at least provide the errors you are seeing but I think that you did not copy the source code properly. Also without the errors we are unable to tell if the errors are in the DB or on the web server ...

Comment: 404 Not Found errors on Linux that don't occur in Windows - these will be caused by wrong casing in the links.

Comment: It's my wrong description, sorry. This app is working properly on both sides (Windows and Linux), I mean add, correct, delete records, filter and display. But one thing isn't good. Pictures. On windows I can upload picture (from my tmp directory to www tmp directory and write it to the database BLOB correcty. On Linux I receive error when I choose such a picture and app can't write it to the database.